# DirectX: about DirectX LockRect()

Tags: directx

I am new to directx, and I am trying to understand why do we need to lock surface before we can manipulate it? Can anyone help me explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `Lock` surfaces and buffers in order to tell the GPU, that you are manipulating these resources. These are necessary to syncronize the GPU and the program running on the CPU.

Comment: Keep in mind that direct manipulation of surfaces by the CPU is by definition not efficient. In other words, if there's a way to do it without locking a surface, that's better (i.e. draw with rendering, not by trying to use memory operations from the CPU to set pixels).